# "init_dgelsd failed init" When using import numpy as np

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run this simple code

```
import numpy as np

my_first_array = np.array([1, 2, 3,4,5])

my_first_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I believe I am using python 3.9 as i just bought this computer and downloaded the newest version.
But keep getting the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oledy/Documents/Skole/Dat200/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you care to read up on the issue here is where I found the [solution](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15947) below.

```
rm -v ~/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/*/*/*/*/*numpy* # clear the pip wheel cache of any built numpy wheels
brew install openblas # make sure OpenBLAS is installed
# activate your virtualenv
OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" pip install numpy # let numpy's setup.py know where OpenBLAS is installed
```